# ERROR:org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, groovy, apache-poi, soapui, jxl

```
fis = new FileInputStream(new File(testDataFilePath));
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
sheet = workbook.getSheet(testCaseName);
```

Here are the list of jars which i have used:

```
ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar

poi-3.9.jar
poi-examples-3.9.jar
poi-excelant-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```

I am getting this in SOAPUI error log. on workbook line.

```
       Mon Jun 05 01:32:29 IST 2017:ERROR:org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:403)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:207)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
at Script2.run(Script2.groovy:30)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:90)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
... 17 more
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.StyleSheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.readFrom(StylesTable.java:121)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.<init>(StylesTable.java:92)
... 22 more
```

Comment: Can you post the script around line number 30 of the script? what soapui version are you using? Do you have `org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader` in your classpath?

Comment: Try latest version of apache-poi-3.16.

Comment: thanks Rao, last night only i tried with poi-3.16. After that i had to deploy commons-collections4-4.1.jar and commons-collections4-4.1-javadoc.jar. And finally it worked.

Comment: Hi @Preet and welcome to stack overflow.  If you have found a solution to the issue, please write it as an answer and accept it, that will help other users if they are having the same issue.  See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more details.